# I want my JFrame to adjust its dimensions and keep the buttons with constant size

Tags: java, button, resize, jframe, resizable

i need to keep my buttons with constant size and re-size the JFrame to adjust to the buttons size, but all i get is a constant size on the JFrame and my buttons re-size according to the amount of buttons.

Here is my code.

Here is where i create my buttons, the number of buttons is chosen by the dimensions received

[campoMinado.getAltura()][campoMinado.getLargura()]

```
      Height                Width
```

botoes[][] is my bi-dimensional array of buttons.

```
for(int y = 0; y < campoMinado.getAltura(); y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < campoMinado.getLargura(); x++){
        botoes[x][y] = new BotaoCampoMinado(x, y);
        botoes[x][y].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        botoes[x][y].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        botoes[x][y].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        botoes[x][y].addActionListener(action);
        botoes[x][y].addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        getContentPane().add(botoes[x][y]);

     }
 }
```

Comment: You need to use the right layout manager. Read the tutorial [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: i'm using grid layout so that the buttons appear as a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the JFrame use .pack();

Ex:

```
JFrame gameField = new JFrame();
gameField.pack();
gameField.setVisible(true);
```